# MVVMLight Messenger Send - Pause method

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm converting a program to MVVM Light from Code Behind.

Part of this software, has to read in a CSV file from our bank, grab all the data, transform it, the copy it into a new CSV that will then get uploaded to our Accounting Software.

Using code behind, whilst reading the CSV, it would open up a new form if it was the first time that credit card had been uploaded, in order to set some defaults up, then once the defaults are set, it would continue processing.

I've been using the MessengerInstance to swap between forms and pass data between viewmodels. But I don't know how to send the message, pause the current running method until a message is sent back.

**Send Message**

```
     selectedCreditCard =
           _creditCardList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CreditCardNumber == existingColumns[1]);
                 if (selectedCreditCard == null)
                 {
                     MessengerInstance.Send(Messaging.FormChanged.NewCreditCard);
                     MessengerInstance.Send(existingColumns[1], Messaging.MessengerTokens.
                  }
```

**Receive Message**

```
  public NewCreditCardViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, Messaging.MessengerTokens.NewCreditCards, value => AccountName = value);

        SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveNewCreditCard);
        RefreshCommand = new RelayCommand(RefreshVendorsAndReviewers);
        CreditCard = new VPCreditCard();
    }
```

Comment: There should be a way to send the message and await using TPL.

Comment: The basic algorithm seems a bit odd to me. Why would you not read all the data in and save it to two tables or classes/objects in memory. The ones you need additional info go into one. The ones are OK go into another. The user then goes through those need more data and completes those they can. These are added to the OK pile. A separate process then turns the ok ones into a csv.

Comment: I can do that. Probably best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly

You want to keep this decoupled with messages, then just send a message back on OK from the defaults form to continue processing. I.e save the state and continue where you left off with the defaults

1. Process CSV part 1 (stop processing, save state, check for new cc)

   1.a - If new cc, send message to defaults form (if not new cc, Process CSV part 2 )

   1.b - Defaults opens, on OK, Send message back processing form
2. Receive finished defaults message, Process CSV part 2 (continue where left off)

The premise is you just have to break CSV processing in to 2 parts, 2 methods, and allow it to resume it self via its state

Comment: I'm trying to minimize the amount of IO/code that happens. The problem is each file may have 10-15 cc on it. I'd have to read the file, do the checks for all cc/defaults, then re read all lines to convert to new csv'

Comment: Using StreamReader